# What in 16.04LTS kernel 4.4.0-72 could cause random reboots?

Tags: 16.04, kernel, reboot

After weeks of troubleshooting and running an old kernel from a live usb for more than 24 hours without a hiccup, I finally decided to use an older kernel on the desktop itself.  The system has now been up for over 4 hours straight on 4.4.0-71.  I think I've narrowed it down to the 4.4.0-72 kernel that is causing random reboots on my desktop.  I've only experienced random reboots while running on the 4.4.0-72 kernel.

Some Troubleshooting I've completed:

I don't see anything to explain the reboots in any log.

```
/var/sys/syslog
/var/sys/kern.log
/var/sys/*  (Any log here)
```

I have disabled automatic reboots in

> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades>

By uncommenting (deleting the “//”) and updating the line to read:

> Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "false";

I have taken my computer apart and unplugged every power cord inside the box to check the Power Supply voltages per https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-manually-test-a-power-supply-with-a-multimeter-2626158

I have checked the Temperatures of all sensors using lmsensors and I have Psensor installed.  Nothing seems to be overheating.  I also dusted/cleaned the fans and heatsinks while I had everything apart.
I've even attempted to make the machine overheat using graphic intensive software that did set off my psensor alarms set at 55 degrees.  The machine normally does not get that warm, and it did not reboot when I made that happen.

I have run the memory tests from a live usb grub menu.

I have checked my SSDs using badblocks from a live usb.

I wouldn't expect an immediate automatic reboot after any of the previous situations and have disabled reboots after a power failure in the BIOS.

I have checked for panic to no avail at

> /proc/sys/kernel/panic

That file contains a single "0" (zero), meaning it was not a panic.

I have not scanned for "viruses" yet.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the random reboots by installing an Nvidia graphics card (GeForce GTX 770) and using the proprietary Nvidia binary driver (375.39) that comes with Ubuntu.  Therefore, I conclude that the problem is in the pre-installed Radeon driver that Ubuntu now uses since fglrx was depricated in 16.04.  Even though the AMD R9 270X is supposedly completely supported on 16.04.